# how can we click continue button in warning window using selenium web driver

Tags: java, selenium

I am new to selenium.....

I've written a selenium code with java for Automation script. while running the script i am getting a Security Warning window which has the options called 'Continue' and 'Stop Script'. How to click Continue through selenium control. There is no  way for getting xpath or id of the continue button.

its not a application window,it is firefox security warning window..So, the alert window method  accept.alert() is not working.

can u please tell me how to handle those type of firefox warning windows.

Comment: add more info, post code. And tell about your environment.

Comment: the python selenium stuff has a call "switch_to_alert()", I would imagine that the java bindings have a similar method

Comment: Do you get the security warning without selenium?  If so, then the bindings are `driver.switchTo().alert()`.  If not, then something weird is going on.

Answer (score 0):

In my code  below two lines of code to solved the problem  "Warning: Unresponsive script " error is coming while running automation script  in Selenium server
By using these two lines of code in setting firefox preferrences.
profile.setPreference("dom.max_chrome_script_run_time", 0);
profile.setPreference("dom.max_script_run_time",  0 );